# Convert MP3 to WAV

Tags: python, sox

I am trying to convert .mp3 file to .wav format. when I am using below command in "command prompt" I am able to get desired output. it gives me output file in .wav format

```
sox "C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.mp3" --rate 16k --bits 16 --channels 1 "C:\Users\Mayank\Desktop\Audio File\Call.wav"
```

I tried to do the same thru Python. Below is the code for that :

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['sox', 'C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.mp3', 
                           '--rate 16k', '--bits 16', '--channels 1', 
                           'C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.wav'])
```

I am getting below error while doing so. I am new with python, please let me know how to achieve this :

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I tried using double "\" instead of "\" then I am getting below error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried all below options also.. all of them gives same error "cannot find the file specified"..

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['sox', "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Audio File\\Call.mp3", 
                           '--rate 16k', '--bits 16', '--channels 1', 
                           "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Audio File\\Call.wav"])


import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['sox', r'C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.mp3', 
                           '--rate 16k', '--bits 16', '--channels 1', 
                           r'C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.wav'])


import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['sox', "C:/Users/Mayank/Desktop/Audio File/Call.mp3", 
                           '--rate 16k', '--bits 16', '--channels 1', 
                           "C:/Users/Desktop/Audio File/Call.wav"])
```

Comment: use forward slashes or a raw string `''C:/Users/Desktop/Audio File/Call.mp3''`, or escape your backslashes `''C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Audio File\\Call.mp3''` or `r'C:\Users\Desktop\Audio File\Call.mp3'`, `'\U` is a unicode identifier, vote to close as this is a typo. Note you will also need to do the same thing for the output path. Regarding your second error, does the file exist?

Comment: I edited my question.. I have tried all these options also.. all of them gives same error. still not able to rectify the issue. :(

Comment: Question: why do you want to do this? MP3 is a compressed format, so by definition you're not going to get any improvement in audio quality, just a bigger file.

Comment: I needed this to feed it to google speech-2-text api... .raw format .. same issue with .raw also..

Comment: looks like in subprocess its not able to find "executable "  

hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                         # no special security
                                         None, None,
                                         int(not close_fds),
                                         creationflags,
                                         env,
                                         cwd,
                                         startupinfo)

Answer (score 3):

sox doesn't support mp3 to wav conversion.
To convert mp3 to wav you can the below mentioned commands. It will work perfectly.

```
pip install pydub

apt-get install ffmpeg
```

MP3 to WAV conversion

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment

# files                                                                         
src = "transcript.mp3"
dst = "test.wav"

# convert wav to mp3                                                            
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
sound.export(dst, format="wav")
```

check out this [link](https://pythonbasics.org/convert-mp3-to-wav/) if it doesn't work

Comment: Sure it does. you just have to install the proper library. I do it all the time. 
sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-mp3
sox file.mp3 file.wav

Answer (score 0):

at last it worked as below

```
import subprocess
sox = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/sox-14-4-2/sox.exe'

infile = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Audio File/Call.mp3'
outfile = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Audio File/Call.wav'
extra = '--rate 16k --bits 16 --channels 1'

command = """{0} "{1}" {2} "{3}" """.format(sox,infile,extra,outfile)
subprocess.call(command)
```